# bottom dropped out

Tags: idioms, vocabulary

I heard this expression and I don't know what it means. I googled it and it was mostly financial meanings. But mine is not. I'm writing the context exactly.

The bottom kind of dropped out when I heard that Amanda was pregnant. Because she wasn't able to take care of herself at that point let alone take care of a child.

Thank you.

Comment: The usage would have started in contexts like *"The bottom dropped out of the market"* (the market fell very sharply, as if not supported by a solid bottom/base). From there things moved on to the idiomatically common form *"The bottom dropped out of my world when she left me"* (***I*** had no underlying support). Your usage seems to me to be an extension too far, but the meaning is clear enough.

Comment: It doesn't seem likely that _your_ bottom would drop when you hear about a problem with someone else, unless it directly affects you. And _the bottom_ would refer to a wide community, not appropriate for a personal tragedy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with both comments: the statement is easily understandable, but the image is overdone. You might instead try something like "**My heart sank** when I heard..."

Or, of course, you can use it anyways, and if enough people imitate you it will become accepted.